# Unity Slider Value not cooperating with being set

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts that I'm currently having problem with. One is attached directly to a slider, which depending on its configuration will either send a slider value to the `Options` for music or sound.

In the Unity editor, I have it so whenever the options menu is brought up, run the `OptionsLevel()` script on both of the sliders to set them to the value saved in my options. I have no errors not being able to find the options, however the sliders do not move themselves to the value I am trying to set them too.

As far as I can tell, this should work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SetVolume : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer Mixer;
    private GameObject canvas;

    [SerializeField] public enum Master { MusicVol, SoundVol }

    public Master master;
    public Slider slider;

    public void OptionsLevel() //Call this when opening menu, changesss the slide layout to what already exits in the options
    {
        if (master.ToString() == "SoundVol")
        {
            Debug.Log("I am being called sound");
            gameObject.GetComponent<Slider>().value = Options.Instance.GetSoundVolume(); //SETS VALUE of Slider, to value in Options
        }

        if (master.ToString() == "MusicVol")
        {
            Debug.Log("I am being called music");
            slider.value = Options.Instance.GetMusicVolume();
        }
    }

    public void SetLevel(float sliderValue)
    {
        Mixer.SetFloat(master.ToString(), Mathf.Log10(sliderValue) * 20); //Reads in the slider value and changes the mixer whenever the slider is changed

        if (master.ToString() == "SoundVol") //if sound then set the sound volume in the settings
        {
            Options.Instance.SetSoundVolume(sliderValue);
        }

        if (master.ToString() == "MusicVol") //if the slider is configured for music it sends a copy of that value to the options
        {
            Options.Instance.SetMusicVolume(sliderValue);
        }
    }
}
```

my options script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Options : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float musicFxVolume; // used to measure the value of sliders
    public float soundFxVolume;
    public float musicRealVolume;
    public float soundRealVolume; //used to measure the actual volume level of the mixer

    #region Singleton

    public static Options Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        SetUpSingleton();
        Instance = this;
    }

    private void SetUpSingleton()
    {
        int numberOptions = FindObjectsOfType<Options>().Length;
        if (numberOptions > 1)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public void SetSoundVolume(float volume) //when called this will make a copy of the volume
    {
        soundFxVolume = volume;

        soundRealVolume = Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20; //and make a copy of the volume sent to the mixuer
        Debug.Log("Setting the sound volume");
    }

    public void SetMusicVolume(float volume)
    {
        musicFxVolume = volume; //just store the value

        musicRealVolume = Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20;
        Debug.Log("Setting the music volume"); 
    }

    public float GetMusicVolume()
    {
        return musicFxVolume; //returns the value of the copied slider
    }

    public float GetSoundVolume()
    {
        return soundFxVolume;
    }
}
```

I'm using Unity 2018.3.14f1, if that matters.

Comment: I suspect its the way you set up your singleton. When a second copy exists (due to loading a scene at run time), which copy persists, the one with the saved volume levels, or the one with all zeros?

Comment: Right! Okay I think I know what you mean. Is there anyway to distinguish the two though? Like what's the simplist way to say, if it already exists, delete self? Because I've tried using ActiveInHierarchy and that doesn't quite work the way I want. Thank you for the enlightenment though!

Comment: On closer inspection it's definitely not the issue with the singleton. I've correct it to keep the one with the values but the issue is directly with setting the slider. I don't think this line of code works .  game object.GetComponent<Slider>().Value